# Wrap plain text mouse selection into a html tag

Tags: javascript

I have an HTML element lets say a div which contains plain text. The text should be selectable and wrap the selection into a tag (mark for example). That is already working.

**HTML Example:**

```html
<div class="highlighter-container">
  This is a <mark>long</mark> sentence
</div>
```

**Expected behaviour:**

- select text and wrap it into a tag ✓
- selecting "is a long sentence" should not merge it into one tag
- selection of "is a long sentence" should stop the selection at the mark tag which would be before "long" - you should not be able to select "is a long sentence"

Currently i'm using mouseup (on the `.highlighter-container` div) to trigger `execute()` then get the selection (using selection api) and replace it with the tag. I'm also disabling user selection with css `user-select: none;` on the mark tag but that doesn't stop the user from selecting further down the text.

**My code so far:**

```js
Highlighter.prototype.execute = function() {
  var selectedText = this.getSelectedText();
  var rawText = selectedText.toString();
  var range = selectedText.getRangeAt(0);

  var highlighted = document.createElement('MARK');
  highlighted.textContent = selectedText.toString();
  highlighted.classList.add(HIGHLIGHTED_CLASS);

  range.deleteContents();
  range.insertNode(highlighted);
};

Highlighter.prototype.getSelectedText = function() {
  var text = (document.all) ? document.selection.createRange().text : document.getSelection();
  return text;
};
```

I tried a few things with the Range API but i'm not sure if its even possible by using the selection api.